# Expo Notification - The request sent to the server was malformed or contained invalid parameters. - DeveloperError

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

I am facing this error when trying to send notifications using `expo-server-sdk`.

Error:

```json
 "ticket": {
      "dataId": "JapfKeSlahLmWbnYMfIl",
      "ticket": {
        "status": "ok",
        "id": "66989d5e-f658-4270-9d01-bed0bfa20170"
      },
      "userId": "h01mZmixVSxmndi951h2",
      "token": "********"
    },
 "receipt": {
      "status": "error",
      "messageParamValues": {},
      "messageEnum": 18,
      "details": {
        "sentAt": 1696894504,
        "errorCodeEnum": 2,
        "fcm": {
          "httpStatus": 404,
          "response": "<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\">\n<H1>Not Found</H1>\n<H2>Error 404</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n"
        },
        "error": "DeveloperError"
      },
      "message": "The request sent to the server was malformed or contained invalid parameters.",
      "__debug": {}
    }
```

- This error is not documented in the [Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/#errors)
- This does not seem to be related to the notification object I'm sending since trying to send it to other tokens worked normally. Here is the notification I am trying to send (I simplified the code to make it more readable)

```js
 let messages: ExpoPushMessage[] = [];
 for (let pushToken of tokens) {
   if (!Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken.token)) {
     continue;
   }
   messages.push({
        to: pushToken.token,
        sound: 'default',
        title: notification.title,
        body: notification.body || '',
        data: {
          dataId: notification.dataId,
          imageUrl: notification.imageUrl,
          title: notification.originalTitle,
          summary: notification.summary,
          teams: notification.teams,
          url: notification.url,
          userId: pushToken.userId,
        },
   });
 }

 let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);

 let bulk = [] as TicketData[];
 for (const chunk of chunks) {
   const ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
 }
```

I have seen this discussion in other places but without any reasonable solution:

- https://forums.expo.dev/t/push-notification-error/21440
- https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4401
- https://forums.expo.dev/t/push-notification-error-the-request-sent-to-the-server-was-malformed-or-contained-invalid-parameters/20310/3
- https://forums.expo.dev/t/undocumented-push-notification-error-from-fcm-developererror/39231

Does anyone know what could be the cause and how to handle this issue?